# Passing Id With bootstrap Model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pass an Id when I open a model from bootstrap. I have a table and want to click on the row to do this. I am using master-pages and I am loading the jquery and bootstrap at the end of the master page.
The Model show up and works but the hidden field never get a value.
Also When I move the script in my Page (not master page) I get the same behavior.

Thanks

Tried so far:

```
<td data-toggle="modal" class="open" data-target="#OpenLine" data-id="<%# Eval("LineId") %>"><%# Eval("Quantity") %></td>
```

with
This is in my master page at the bottom

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Libraries/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Libraries/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Libraries/Jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Libraries/Jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Libraries/Jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Css/simple-sidebar.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="../../Libraries/Jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Libraries/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Libraries/Jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Javascript/timepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {

        var active = true;

        $('#collapse-init').click(function () {
            if (active) {
                active = false;
                $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
                $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', '');
                $(this).text('Enable accordion behavior');
            } else {
                active = true;
                $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
                $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
                $(this).text('Disable accordion behavior');
            }
        });

        $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            if (active) $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
        });

    });

    $(".open").click(function () {
        var myBookId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $("ContentPlaceHolder1_Content3_HLineNumber").val(myBookId);
        // As pointed out in comments, 
        // it is superfluous to have to manually call the modal.
        // $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
        alert(myBookId);
    });
</script>
```

My Model

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="OpenLine" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Order Line</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; background-color: #F7F7F7;">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HLineNumber" runat="server" />
                <div id="LeftPane" style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 620px; position: relative; float: left; background-color: white;">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="background-color: white;">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Basic" aria-controls="Basic" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" aria-hidden="true"></span>Basic</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Styling" aria-controls="Styling" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Styling</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content" style="background-color: white;">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Basic">
                            <table style="margin: 10px; padding: 10px; text-align: left;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Model: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TModel" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Species: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TSpecies" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Thickness: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TThickness" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Width: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TWidth" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Height: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="THeight" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Stile Width: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TStileWidth" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Top Rail: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TTopRail" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Sticking: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TSticking" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Panel: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TPanel" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fire Rating: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TFireRating" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Styling">
                            <table style="margin: 10px; padding: 10px; text-align: left;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Glass Type: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TGlassType" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Glass Thickness: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TGlassThickness" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Louver Type: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TLouverType" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Louver Size: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TLouverSize" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Dutch Door: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="YesDucth" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="Dutch" />
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="NoDutch" runat="server" Text="No" Checked="True" GroupName="Dutch" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Veneer: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Veneer" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Bevel: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Bevel" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Swing: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Swing" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" runat="server" Height="30"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Protection Film: </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 5px;">
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="YesFilm" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="Film" />
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="NoFilm" runat="server" Text="No" Checked="True" GroupName="Film" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="RightPane" style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; height: 620px; background-color: white;">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="background-color: white;">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#image" aria-controls="image" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>Image</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Description" aria-controls="Description" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>Description</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Pricing" aria-controls="Pricing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" aria-hidden="true"></span>Pricing</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content" style="background-color: white;">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="image">
                            <%if (ImagePath != "")
                              { %>
                            <embed id="svgImage" src="<%=ImagePath %>" type="image/svg+xml" class="svg-image" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" wmode="transparent" style="height: 568px;" />
                            <%} %>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Description">...</div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Pricing">...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="BSaveLine" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Save" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField7" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField8" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField9" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean modal, not model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).data('id');` should actually be `$(this).attr('data-id');`

and also ContentPlaceHolder1_Content3_HLineNumber does not exists in the code you provided. So the value goes no where

Comment: This might be true, Al tho it did not fix the problem. Also on debugging the jquery in chrome the function does not fire when clicking on the table row.

Comment: Oh. What i usually do is put alerts or console.log in parts of the code to see where is does not work/break. You should try it and see where it stops

Comment: Do `alert( myBookId )` right after you get the data ans see if it pops up  because i see nothing wrong with you code except for the `'ContentPlaceHolder1_Content3_HLineNumber'`. If the value does not show then check your jquery link and make sure that you are loading jquery before writing the click funtion.

Comment: Then you are probably not loading the jquery script beforehand and it can also be that you create the function before your table data was created.

Add these 2 lines 

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` before your `<script>` tags containing the js code above

Comment: see edit on how I have it loaded. I do have the function created after the table is created

Comment: change you click function to this:

$(".open").click(function () {
        var myBookId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        alert(myBookId);
});

Comment: Also open up your console and see if there are error messages. An error in your  above can cause any other function after it to not work.

Comment: I had an error in another part but that fixed it thanks

Comment: No problem. Good luck and hope you reach your goals.